# Moments of a Normal-Wishart distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, moments

Do known expressions exist for the moments of a gaussian-wishart (aka normal wishart) distribution?

$$NW(\mu,K\mid\mu_0,\lambda_0, v, W) = 
\frac{|\lambda_0K|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}e^{-0.5([\mu - \mu_0]^T \lambda_0K[\mu-\mu_0])}\frac{|K| ^{(v-d-1)/2}}{2^{vd/2}|W|^{v/2}\Gamma_d\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)} e^{-\operatorname{tr}(W^{-1}K)/2}$$

Comment: [All Invariant Moments of the Wishart Distribution](http://massamh.info.yorku.ca/files/2016/04/sjos_391.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Carlo, I am however looking for the moments of a Gaussian-Wishart distribution and not the moments of the Wishart distribution.

Comment: apologies if I am confused: but moments of $K$ are moments of the Wishart distribution (and moments of $\mu$ are moments of a t-distribution), so these are not the ones you want to know? [I presume your $u$ is $\mu$, right?]

Comment: Do you mean to calculate the moments of $\mu$ and K separately from their respective marginals? (Yes u is $\mu$, sorry for the typo, I have fixed it now)

Comment: if all you need are moments of $\mu$ and $K$, the marginals should suffice, wouldn't they?

Comment: I am actually very unsure about the moments of the Gaussian-Wishart. I am mainly interested in finding them in order to do moment matching for distribution approximation. One thing that bothers me about taking the moments of the marginals is that it seems as though it would throw away information about the dependence between mu and K. For instance,  doing the same for a multivariate gaussian (taken the moments of the marginals, one will not be able to construct the full covariance matrix.

Comment: By the way this is still relating to the problem of the Gaussian-Wishart approximation (which you also commented on). Did you by any chance find out anything more about that problem?

Comment: It is a random vector. How do you define the moments ? Componentwise ?